# Raw ICMP packets are showing no answers while ping messages do get replies

Tags: python, python-3.x, scapy

I have the following script lines which send raw ICMP packet to a certain device:

```
from scapy.all import sr1

pkt = IP(dst=device_ip) / ICMP()
sr1(pkt, timeout=5, verbose=0)
```

When I am running these script lines in my Windows 7 PC (Python 3.5.2) I always get answers as I expect.
But, when I run the same lines from my Windows 10 (Python 3.8.3) only sometimes I get answers. Although I know for sure that the device answers to the ICMP requests (I see the ICMP replies with a sniffer). By the way, I have even tried a TO of 10 seconds and I also tried to use **iface** with the relevant interface and that didn't help.
I know that I have at least one more difference between the stations, the windows 7 has a Winpcap and the Windows 10 has the Npcap (version 0.999). Besides that both run the same scapy version 2.4.3.

What may go wrong ?

Where do I need to start looking ?